# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')

Tags: ajax, javascript, jquery

I wrote authentication for the entry and membership of wordpress.
The code I wrote is ajax.
not work Validation and redirect.
But he gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')
at Object.error (auth.js?ver=1:74:54)
at c (jquery.min.js?ver=1:2:28294)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js?ver=1:2:29039)
at l (jquery.min.js?ver=1:2:79825)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?ver=1:2:82254)
```

Codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#loginForm').on('submit', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    let user_email = $('#userEmail').val();
    let user_password = $('#userPassword').val();
    let notify = $('.alert');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'wp_auth_login',
            user_email: user_email,
            user_password: user_password
        },
        success: function (response){

            if(response.success)
            {
                notify.removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
                notify.append('<p>' + response.message + '</p>')
                notify.show(300);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href = '/';
                }, 2000);
            }
        },
        error: function (error){
            if(error){
                let message = error.responseJSON.message;
                notify.addClass('alert-danger');
                notify.append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
                notify.css('display', 'block');
                notify.delay(2000).hide(300);
            }
        }
    });
});

$('#registerForm').on('submit', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    let first_name = $('#user_first_name').val();
    let last_name = $('#user_last_name').val();
    let user_email = $('#user_email').val();
    let user_password = $('#user_password').val();
    let notify = $('.alert');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'wp_auth_register',
            user_first_name: first_name,
            user_last_name: last_name,
            user_email: user_email,
            user_password: user_password
        },
        success: function (response){
            if(response.success)
            {
                notify.removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
                notify.append('<p>' + response.message + '</p>')
                notify.show(300);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href = 'wp-admin/profile';
                }, 2000);
            }
        },
        error: function (error){
            if(error){
                let message = error.responseJSON.message;
                notify.addClass('alert-danger');
                notify.append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
                notify.css('display', 'block');
                notify.delay(2000).hide(300);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});

Calls:

```
function wp_auth_load_file()
{
   wp_register_script('auth_script',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/auth.js', 
   array('jquery'), true );
   wp_enqueue_script('auth_script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_auth_load_file');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a question is considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our site, as it pertains explicitly to JavaScript and jQuery syntax rather than WordPress or it's APIs. That said, the problem is likely the `error.responseJSON.message` in your `error` callback - `responseJSON` is not a valid property on jQuery's jqXHR object within the `error` handler - it only exists in a `success` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's sure from the undefined variable message. I suggest to log these variable response.message, error.responseJSON.message.